# Is it possible to know why exactly [user] left?

Tags: discussion

It was around, I think, last month that someone in chat noticed that [a specific user] left Physics.SE. I felt somewhat uneasy by that (and I know everyone must have felt it) because he left without any notice. I used to talk to him friendly and he was the one who taught by his small comment that

> Gravity is no longer a force in General Relativity

Recently I saw a meta post and in that @G.Smith sir has disclosed it very briefly that [this user] didn’t leave due *dramas* that is going on by CMs of SE but he got problems with the users of PSE. Does anyone know what was this reason? And if someone know it can he/she consider saying it here?

Is it possible to know what really happened to [them]? Can moderators contact him through email and ask him if I can get his email address (I mean can moderators share his email address if [the user] allows them to do so) ?

Comment: I've edited this post so that it's not about any specific individual. General answers are okay, but if someone wants to leave our community without announcing why, we shouldn't react by making an announcement on their behalf.

Comment: I feel like based on when you have asked questions like this in chat and how moderators have replied in chat, you should know the answer to your question already.

Comment: @AaronStevens Come on! When I asked it in chats? Give me the transcript when moderators in chats told me that they cannot reveal it. Do you got the transcripts?

Comment: I might be conflating with some discussions on meta, but I seem to recall you being a part of discussions about people being anonymous on this site, the role of moderators in terms of other users' identities, etc. I wasn't claiming you had asked this exact question before. In any case I don't want to get you worked up, so we can just end this talk now.

Comment: In my opinion asking for this kind of information or contacting a user who has decided to leave is improper and impolite: this site is not Hotel California.  If a user is interested in keeping contact with the community at large, he or she can easily arrange to do this, and not doing so is a cue to leave this person alone.

Answer (score 5):

We're an anonymous and pseudonymous internet community. People come and go. Some of us offer reasons; some of us keep those details quiet.

If you know someone's identity off-site, it's up to you to decide whether it's appropriate to contact them through another channel.

The diamond moderators cannot reveal anyone's personally-identifying information. Doing so would violate our moderator agreement.

Comment: Means we have no chance of contacting him? I understand that disclosing him email will be like disclosing something personal.

Comment: Some users have chosen to make their real identities public. (Others have not.) Stack Exchange is not the entire internet.

Comment: “Stack Exchange is not the entire internet” I’m really having trouble in understanding this. Please tell me what you are indicating by it.

Comment: @KnightadmiresChappo If you think you know their real name there might be other ways to find/contact them.

Comment: (some comments deleted) Please refrain from making this about a specific user, everyone. Thank you.